# Why I can log in amazon website using python mechanize, but not requests or urllib2

Tags: python, web, authentication, mechanize

I can use the following piece of python code found from [here](http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2011/01/15/backup-your-amazon-order-history-with-python.html) to log into amazon.com:

```
import mechanize 

br = mechanize.Browser()  
br.set_handle_robots(False)  
br.addheaders = [("User-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101206 Ubuntu/10.10 (maverick) Firefox/3.6.13")]  

sign_in = br.open('https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html')  

br.select_form(name="sign-in")  
br["email"] = 'test@test.com' 
br["password"] = 'test4test'
logged_in = br.submit() 

orders_html = br.open("https://www.amazon.com/gp/css/history/orders/view.html?orderFilter=year-%s&startAtIndex=1000" % 2013)
```

But following two pieces using requests module and urllib2 do not work.

```
import requests
import sys

username = "test@test.com"
password = "test4test"

login_data = ({
        'email' : fb_username,
        'password' : fb_password,
        'flex_password': 'true'})

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html'

agent ={'User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.57 Safari/537.1'}

session = requests.session(config={'verbose': sys.stderr}, headers = agent)

r = session.get('http://www.amazon.com')

r1 = session.post(url, data=login_data, cookies=r.cookies)

r2 = session.post("https://www.amazon.com/gp/css/history/orders/view.html?orderFilter=year-2013&startAtIndex=1000", cookies = r1.cookies)
```

### #

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import cookielib

amazon_username = "test@test.com"
amazon_password = "test4test"
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html'

cookie = cookielib.CookieJar()
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'email' : amazon_username, 'password' : amazon_password,})

opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.57 Safari/537.1')]

opener.open('www.amazon.com')

response = opener.open(url, login_data)

response = opener.open("https://www.amazon.com/gp/css/history/orders/view.html?orderFilter=year-%s&startAtIndex=1000" % 2013, login_data)
```

What did I do wrong in posting the amazon log in form? This is the first time I post a form. Any help is appreciated.

I prefer to use urllib2 or requests because all my other code are using these two modules.

Moreover, can any body comment on the speed performance between mechanize, requests and urllib2, and other advantage of mechanize over the other two?

~~~~~~~~~~~New~~~~~~~~~~~~
Following C.C.'s instruction, I now can log in with urllib2. But when I try to do the same with requests, it still does not work. Can anyone give me a clue?

```
import requests
import sys

fb_username = "test@test.com"
fb_password = "xxxx"

login_data = ({
            'email' : fb_username,
            'password' : fb_password,
            'action': 'sign-in'})

url = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html'

agent ={'User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.57 Safari/537.1'}

session = requests.session(config={'verbose': sys.stderr}, headers = agent)

r = session.get(url)

r1 = session.post('https://www.amazon.com/gp/flex/sign-in/select.html', data=login_data, cookies=r.cookies)

b = r1.text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your `urllib2` approach, you are missing 2 things.

First, if you look at the source of `sign-in.html`, it shows that

```
<form name="sign-in" id="sign-in" action="/gp/flex/sign-in/select.html" method="POST">
```

Meaning the form should be submitted to `select.html`.

Second, besides email & password, you also need to select whether you are an existing user or not:

```
<input id="newCust" type="radio" name="action" value="new-user"...>
...
<input id="returningCust" type="radio" name="action" value="sign-in"...>
```

It should look something like this:

```
import cookielib
import urllib
import urllib2

amazon_username = ...
amazon_password = ...

login_data = urllib.urlencode({'action': 'sign-in',
                               'email': amazon_username,
                               'password': amazon_password,
                               })

cookie = cookielib.CookieJar()    
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', ...)]

response = opener.open('https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html')
print(response.getcode())

response = opener.open('https://www.amazon.com/gp/flex/sign-in/select.html', login_data)
print(response.getcode())

response = opener.open("https://www.amazon.com/") # it should show that you are logged in
print(response.getcode())
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

It does work now for urllib2. However when I try to do the same with python requests module. It still does not work. Can anyone give me a clue?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to login to Amazon using `requests`.

```
from getpass import getpass
import webbrowser
import requests
import os


amazon_username = raw_input("Amazon email: ")
amazon_password = getpass()

headers = {
    "User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36",
    "action": "sign-in",
    "email": amazon_username,
    "password": amazon_password
    }

r = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com/gp/sign-in.html", headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)

r = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com/gp/flex/sign-in/select.html", headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)

r = requests.get("https://www.amazon.com/", headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
```